# Infinite loop active record

Tags: ruby

When the user attempts to login and enters a username that doesn't exist along with their password what I want the method called existing_user to do is to continue to show the login menu (login_screen_selection). The problem is that once the menu appears again and the user enters '1' which is supposed to prompt them for the username again, the program terminates. I want the method to behave like an infinite loop that can only break if you enter a username that already exists

```rb
def process_login
  case login_screen_selection
  when '1'
    existing_user
  when '2'
    create_account
  when '3'
    exit_application
  else
    process_login
  end
end

def login_screen_selection
  puts "1. Login"
  puts "2. Create account"
  puts "3. Exit"
  gets.chomp
end

def existing_user
  puts "Please Enter Username"
  get_username = gets.chomp

  puts "Please Enter Password"
  get_password = gets.chomp

  customer = Customer.find_by(
    username: get_username,
    password: get_password
    )

  if customer.nil? do
    puts 'Sorry, username and/or password combination not valid. Please try again'
    login_screen_selection 
    break if !customer.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a really bad habit to get into to store plain-text passwords. Always use some kind of password-specific hash, like [Bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) or better.

Comment: @theTinMan Sure, they are  approved, which is probably why they're a super bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go inside the loop. You will be there until you find customer. If so the program will continue and you show menu.

```
def existing_user
  loop do
    puts "Please Enter Username"
    get_username = gets.chomp

    puts "Please Enter Password"
    get_password = gets.chomp

    customer = Customer.find_by(
      username: get_username,
      password: get_password
    )

    break if customer

    puts 'Sorry, username and/or password combination not valid. Please try again'
  end

  login_screen_selection
end
```

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some good answers. I'll just add that the checking for `if customer.nil?` or `if customer` or variations thereof are not necessary if you do something like:

```
def existing_user
  puts "Please Enter Username"
  username = gets.chomp

  puts "Please Enter Password"
  password = gets.chomp

  unless customer = Customer.find_by(
                      username: username,
                      password: password
                    )
    puts 'Sorry, username and/or password combination not valid. Please try again'
    process_login
  end
end
```

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to upvote if you are so inclined.

Comment: Rather than say "Feel free to upvote..." add a comment to the original question with a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. It's important to remember that SO isn't about gaining points, it's about paying it forward and helping others. Points are inconsequential except they provide additional responsibilities on the site.

Comment: Was that little lecture for my benefit?

Answer (score 0):

You want a loop, so write a loop:

```rb
   def existing_user
     while customer.nil? do
       puts "Please Enter Username"
       get_username = gets.chomp

       puts "Please Enter Password"
       get_password = gets.chomp

      customer = Customer.find_by(
        username: get_username,
        password: get_password
      )

      if customer.nil? do
        puts 'Sorry, username and/or password combination not valid. Please try again'
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one mistake stops you from there, in `existing_user` function, you should call `process_login` other than `login_screen_selection`. `login_screen_selection` just puts a message and wait for an input, if it receives an input, program ends.

```rb
def existing_user
  puts "Please Enter Username"
  get_username = gets.chomp

  puts "Please Enter Password"
  get_password = gets.chomp

  customer = Customer.find_by(
    username: get_username,
    password: get_password
    )

  if customer.nil? do
    puts 'Sorry, username and/or password combination not valid. Please try again'
    process_login
  end
end
```